# How I prevent hiding the div again when click on submit button

Tags: html, jquery

When clicking on the checkbox it hides currently displaying DIV & shows hidden DIV. After this hidden div displayed it has a form to submit on button click.

My problem is when i click on this submit button, the form is hiding again. I have tried **stopPropagation()**, **preventDefault()** and many ways & problem still exist. When I use **preventDefault()** then it shows the div without hiding but the submit is disabled.

I saw many questions related this.but nothing works to me. I want to submit form without hiding the div which the form resides. I'm a beginner with jquery.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#active").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#donorTeam").show();
      $("#donor").hide();
    } else {
      $("#donorTeam").hide();
      $("#donor").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="active"> select type

<div id="donor" style="display:block;"></div>

<div id="donorTeam" style="display:none;">
  <form>
    <button type="submit" id="sub">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try either of these 2 approaches

1.

```
    $(function () {
    $('#donorTeam form').on('submit',function (e) {

            // Ajax call here
          e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

2 . add  onsubmit="return false" to the form attribute

```
<form onsubmit="return false"> 
   <button type="submit" id="sub">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think the form will not submit at all. (?)

Comment: Thanks.It doesn't hide the div.but now how can I submit the form.Please .I want to submit the form.

Comment: you simply make an ajax call to submit you form data to the required endpoint   $('#donorTeam form').on('submit',function (e) {

              $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'URL HERE',
                data: $('#myFormName').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                 alert("test!");
                }
              });
          e.preventDefault();
        });